# C# WPF autocomplete Combobox with database

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I want to create a combo box that works like google search for a field in a database. I added the database as data source in my VS 2015. Can I add then the data set directly to my combo box? Because the database doesn't show up in the data source property of the combo box. I use a MariaDB and the MySQL connector 6.9.8 because in 6.9.9 it seems there is a bug with data set in VS.

**Before answering** I don´t want to have a method at the start at my program and then bind a List to the combo box...this is not a problem. And wouldn't work for this because because entries can get updated every minute. I want a combo box with real time search in database for entries.
Therefore, is there a good solution for this problem? I've looked up some possible solutions but they were only for WinForms or in my case, the data binding to the database doesn't work.

Comment: You kinda have to solve this with code since you'd probably want to query the database for only those items that match what has been entered in the text field. And, having done a lot of WPF in the recent years, the attempt to do everything declaratively with XAML, bindings, and eschewing code, tends to be a horrible approach. Nothing wrong with the tools WPF gives you, but know when switching to code is a better option than forcing everything through XAML. And that's as much a maintainability issue as it's a performance one.

Comment: So I should rather make a method that I call everytime on start up to fill the combobox with the entries. How can I implement then a search function over the combo box?

Comment: Can you first go though result #2 through 6 in [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=WPF+autocomplete+Combobox+with+database&rlz=1C1PRFC_enIN690IN690&oq=WPF+autocomplete+Combobox+with+database&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Google search? #1 is your post because I search with exact title.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801004/WPF-AutoComplete-TextBox) will do. Even though it's technically a TextBox, it behaves pretty much exactly like Goolge's search field does, and it's very easy to use.

Basically all you have to do is put an AutoCompleteTextBox in your XAML and bind it to a suggestion provider, which is a class that contains a GetSuggestions method that will get the items from the database.

**Foo.cs :**

```
class Foo
{
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public Foo(string p_label)
    {
        Label = p_label;
    }
}
```

**SuggestionProvider.cs :**

```
class SuggestionProvider
{
    public IEnumerable GetSuggestions(string filter)
    {
        var returnList = new List<Foo>();

        foreach(/* Get items from the databse */)
        {
            returnList.Add(new Foo(/* Label from database */));
        }

        return returnList;
    }
}
```

**XAML :**

```
<!-- ... -->

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

<WpfControls:AutoCompleteTextBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemTemplate}"
                                 Provider="{Binding Path=SuggestionProvider}"
                                 DisplayMember="Label"/>
```

The SuggestionProvider's GetSuggestions method will be executed every time you type something in the AutoCompleteTextBox's editor (the text field) and will return a list of objects. These objects will then be used to build up the suggestions popup as per the DataTemplate you defined. The AutoCompleteTextBox's DisplayMember property is the member (property) of your object that should be displayed in the editor once an object has been selected.

The SuggestionProvider's filter is the text entered in the editor (search field).

There's a little more work to do if you want it to do something as soon as something is selected (when you click an item), but I can help you with this as well if you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. I imported the TextBox now in my Project. Next I generated an ItemTemplate for what class I want to use. Unfortunately it doesn´t work. On the website of the TextBox I read, that it supports MVVM, too but the TextBox doesn´t offer the Binding or ItemsSource propterty. Thoughts?

Comment: The TextBox doesn't expose an ItemsSource property indeed, because the items are obtained from the SuggestionProvider, as shown in my example. I'll update my answer with a more detailed example of how to use the item template and suggestion provider.

Comment: your:  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}/> is missing an "...change it for  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>